# Hide the element text on line charts since it overlaps with the line

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm having troubles trying to find how to hide the element values so they aren't displayed on the line chart itself. I'm using the latest 2.9.3 version by the way.

It's producing an overlap effect that is pretty awful as you can see.

Any ideas or a place in the documentation (have spent a lot of time with this, but didn't figure out how to achieve it). In the bar chart, the element values aren't displayed by default. And in the Line example (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) it doesn't appear. I've tried copying the script that it's being used in that example, but the value continues appearing in the line.

Thanks in advance. I believe it must be super simple to change, but cannot make it.

[image]

**Edit (added sample code)**

```
let daysChartCtx = document.getElementById(chartDataCanvasId);
let daysChart = new Chart(daysChartCtx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
            labels: ["2 Jul","3 Jul"],
            datasets: [{
                data: [17,3],
                backgroundColor: "#f7da4799",
                borderColor: "#c9a804",
                borderWidth: 2
            }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your code that produces above chart?

Comment: @uminder just added it. To be honest, I don't believe the issue is on the code. Since I've copy pasted, literally, the same code it's been used in the Line chart page, and produces the same effect (data values overlap with the line causing it legibility issues).

Answer (score 2):

Chart.js by default doesn't show values on top of data points. The issue must be related to `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` or some other script library you imported on your HTML page.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>
```

Simply remove that and you won't see the the values on top of your data points anymore.

**UPDATE**

From the [chartjs-plugin-datalabels documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration)

> This plugin registers itself globally, meaning that once imported, all charts will display labels. In case you want it enabled only for a few charts, you first need to unregister it globally:

```
Chart.plugins.unregister(ChartDataLabels);
```

> Then, you can enabled the plugin only for specific charts:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    options: {
        // ...
    }
})
```

Comment: That's correct. I had that script loaded, since I included it on a different project as well. I I guess I did need it to do some extra functionalities. However, it'd be nice to know how to disabled this effect without having to remove this plugin. It might be needed and it's an undesired effect. Perhaps even a bug¿?

Comment: @xarlymg89: It's not a bug...I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for this valuable info :)